# Flutter: Update scrollView physic without rebuild

Tags: flutter, scrollview, flutter-sliver

I have created a custom `SliverPersistentHeader` that expands by stretching (over scroll) the scrollview to cover entire screen.

[image]

Red border is device screen.

`SliverPersitentDelegate` observes the scroll position and if it reached the trigger offset, it ask the `_RenderFleixbleHeader` to open the map.
`_RenderFleixbleHeader`  is a subclass of `RenderSliverPinnedPersistentHeader` and is `CustomSliverPersistentHeader`'s `RenderSliver`. it uses an animation controller and in each tick it calls `markNeedsLayout` to `performLayout` for new height.

the problem is when I drag over header, the scrollView still drag. I want to lock the scrollview and only by tapping on the close button reset the layout.

so as you see I don't call `setState` to change widget configuration. so I can not rebuild the CustomScrollView widget which container slivers with new `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` physic to prevent scrolling.

in `SliverPersitentDelegate` I have access to Scrollable `ScrollPosition` and `ScrollController`.

I'm wondering is it possible to inject new physic through `ScrollController`?

I used this but no success:

```dart
final scrollController = Scrollable.of(context)?.widget.controller;
scrollController.detach(_oldPosition);
final newPosition = scrollController.createScrollPosition(
          NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), Scrollable.of(context), _oldPosition);
scrollController.attach(newPosition);
```

any idea?